# running total for N days with mysql

Tags: mysql, join, window-functions, cumulative-sum

i have a table that looks like this :
[image]

what i need is For each day show the accumulated (moving) number of new Droppers in the last 5 days inclusive
Split to US vs. Non-US geos.
 Report Columns:
DataTimstamp - upper boundary of a 5-day time frame
Total - number of New Droppers within the time frame 
Region_US - number of New Droppers where country =’US’
Region_rest - number of New Droppers where country<>’US’

this is my code :

```
    Create view new_droppers_per_date as Select date,country,count(dropperid) as num_new_customers 
   From(
   Select dropper id,country,min(cast( LoginTimestamp as date))  as date 
   From droppers) as t1 group by date,country
   Select DataTimstamp,region_us,region_rest from(
   (Select  date as DataTimstamp ,sum(num_new_customers) over(oreder by date range between 5 
   preceding and 1 preceding) as total
   From new_droppers_per_date ) as t1 inner join 
   (Select date ,sum(num_new_customers) over(oreder by date range between 5 preceding and preceding) 
   as  region_us
  From new_droppers_per_date where country=”us”) as t2 on t1.date=t2.date inner join 
  (Select date, sum(num_new_customers) over(oreder by date range between 5 preceding and 1 
  preceding) 
  as region_rest 
   From new_droppers_per_date where country <>”us”) as t3 on t2.date=t3.date)
```

i was wondering if there is any easier\smarter  way to do so without using so many joins and view

thank you for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using window functions. First assign a flag to the first login of each `DropperId`, then aggregate by day and count the number of new logins. Finally, make a window `sum()` with a `range` frame that spans over the last 5 days.

```
select
    LoginDay,
    sum(CntNewDroppers) over(
        order by LoginDay 
        range between interval 5 day preceding and current row
    ) RunningCntNewDroppers
from 
    select
        date(LoginTimestamp) LoginDay,
        sum(rn = 1) CntNewDroppers
    from (
        select 
            LoginTimestamp, 
            row_number() over(partition by DropperId order by LoginTimestamp) rn
        from mytable
    ) t
) t
```